# Debugging Android App crash

Tags: java, python, android, jython

hello I am trying to debug the crash of an Android app an outdated android app that I have been working on. The app is the Jython Interpreter for Android so far I have managed to compile a debug binary and am hoping some one could shed some light on this error message of logcat thank you

```
I/ActivityManager(   51): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.
MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.python.util/.
Jythonroid }
I/ActivityManager(   51): Start proc org.python.util for activity org.python.uti
l/.Jythonroid: pid=190 uid=10028 gids={1015}
D/dalvikvm(   30): GC freed 284 objects / 10864 bytes in 318ms
D/dalvikvm(   30): GC freed 50 objects / 2216 bytes in 117ms
D/dalvikvm(   30): GC freed 2 objects / 48 bytes in 96ms
D/dalvikvm(   51): GC freed 13347 objects / 617528 bytes in 195ms
I/ARMAssembler(   51): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00000001_00000000 [
 73 ipp] (95 ins) at [0x4c0640:0x4c07bc] in 894130 ns
I/ARMAssembler(   51): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [
 47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x4c19b0:0x4c1abc] in 640894 ns
D/AndroidRuntime(  190): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  190): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4
001b188)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught e
xception
E/AndroidRuntime(  190): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
mponentInfo{org.python.util/org.python.util.Jythonroid}: java.lang.IllegalStateE
xception: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() o
n the child's parent first.
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
ity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivi
ty(ActivityThread.java:2512)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(Activi
tyThread.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Ac
tivityThread.java:1863)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
21)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(  190): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specifi
ed child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent
first.
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup
.java:1861)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java
:1756)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java
:1736)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.
setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:217)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.
setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.
java:1633)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at org.python.util.Jythonroid.onCreate(Jythonroi
d.java:251)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCre
ate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
ity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        ... 11 more
I/Process (   51): Sending signal. PID: 190 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  190): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
E/dalvikvm(  190): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permi
ssion denied
I/ARMAssembler(   51): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [
 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x4c1ac0:0x4c1b7c] in 405177 ns
I/ARMAssembler(   51): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [
 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x492b80:0x492d48] in 494049 ns
W/ActivityManager(   51): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
W/ActivityManager(   51): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43db26a8 org.p
ython.util/.Jythonroid}
D/dalvikvm(   97): GC freed 965 objects / 44888 bytes in 164ms
I/Process (  190): Sending signal. PID: 190 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(   51): Process org.python.util (pid 190) has died.
I/UsageStats(   51): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already res
umed in org.python.util
W/InputManagerService(   51): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: co
m.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43c6ef58
E/gralloc (   51): [unregister] handle 0x3d0690 still locked (state=40000001)
```

Below is the onCreate method

cheers

Below is the onCreate Method

```
/**
 * provide an interactive shell in the screen
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    shell = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shell);
    //      shell=new ShellEditer(this, null, null);
    setContentView(shell);
    shell.setEnabled(false);
    initializeShell(shell);
    Handler hd = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.getData().containsKey("initial")) {
                alert("initialized");
                shell.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                shell.append("\n"+(String) msg.getData().get("result"));
            }
        }
    };
    //running the backend
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                        "dalvikvm -classpath "
                                + "/data/app/Jythonroid.apk "
                                + "org.python.util.JythonServer");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, "JythonServer").start();
    shellclient = new ShellClient(this, hd);
    new Thread(shellclient).start();
}
```

I am now getting the following error trying to run this app from the shell any idea how I can achieve what I am after

```
$ dalvikvm -classpath org.python.util.apk org.python.util.jython
dalvikvm -classpath org.python.util.apk org.python.util.jython
Dalvik VM unable to locate class 'org/python/util/jython'
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.python.util.jython
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.python.util.jython in loader da
lvik.system.PathClassLoader@4001e590
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
        ... 1 more
$
```

it seems it can't find the Path and honestly I am not sure where it is. In the FixMe.java file of my project I set it to

```
public static String apkpath = "/data/app";
public static String apkname = "org.python.util.apk";
public static String apppath = apkpath + apkname;
public static String tmpdirpath = "/data/jythonroid/";
```

But I am unsure that I can write to those paths what should I set those to *cheers

last update I solved most my problems and now get a shell just I get a few errors when running it any ideas how to fix these cheers

```
# dalvikvm -classpath /data/app/org.python.util.apk org.python.util.jython
dalvikvm -classpath /data/app/org.python.util.apk org.python.util.jython
Jython 2.2.1 on java0
Apr 11, 2011 7:40:14 PM java.io.BufferedReader <init>
INFO: Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better
 to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
java.io.IOException: unable to open DEX file
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:82)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:57)
        at org.python.debug.FixMe.getClassByName(FixMe.java:104)
        at org.python.debug.FixMe.getDexClass(FixMe.java:356)
        at org.python.core.BytecodeLoader2.loadClassFromBytes(BytecodeLoader2.ja
va:44)
        at org.python.core.BytecodeLoader.makeClass(BytecodeLoader.java:92)
        at org.python.core.BytecodeLoader.makeCode(BytecodeLoader.java:103)
        at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:1685)
        at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:1698)
        at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:1706)
        at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java:135)
        at org.python.util.InteractiveConsole.interact(InteractiveConsole.java:7
3)
        at org.python.util.jython.main(jython.java:251)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
java.io.IOException: unable to open DEX file
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:82)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:57)
        at org.python.debug.FixMe.getClassByName(FixMe.java:104)
        at org.python.debug.FixMe.getDexClass(FixMe.java:357)
        at org.python.core.BytecodeLoader2.loadClassFromBytes(BytecodeLoader2.ja
va:44)
        at org.python.core.BytecodeLoader.makeClass(BytecodeLoader.java:92)
        at org.python.core.BytecodeLoader.makeCode(BytecodeLoader.java:103)
        at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:1685)
        at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:1698)
        at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:1706)
        at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java:135)
        at org.python.util.InteractiveConsole.interact(InteractiveConsole.java:7
3)
        at org.python.util.jython.main(jython.java:251)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
java.io.IOException: unable to open DEX file
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:82)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:57)
        at org.python.debug.FixMe.getClassByName(FixMe.java:104)
        at org.python.debug.FixMe.getDexClass(FixMe.java:360)
        at org.python.core.BytecodeLoader2.loadClassFromBytes(BytecodeLoader2.ja
va:44)
        at org.python.core.BytecodeLoader.makeClass(BytecodeLoader.java:92)
        at org.python.core.BytecodeLoader.makeCode(BytecodeLoader.java:103)
        at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:1685)
        at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:1698)
        at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:1706)
        at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java:135)
        at org.python.util.InteractiveConsole.interact(InteractiveConsole.java:7
3)
        at org.python.util.jython.main(jython.java:251)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem looks like you are adding a child view to another view - but that child view has already been added. Are you dynamically adding a view or building a layout?`E/AndroidRuntime(  190):        at org.python.util.Jythonroid.onCreate(Jythonroi
d.java:251)`

Comment: By the look of the onCreate method it looks like I am creating a view for the shell.

thanks for your help I am no expert at Java just trying to hack my way through this.

cheers
I have added the onCreate method to an edit in the original post if you care to take a look

Answer (score 0):

This call seems to be out of place

```
setContentView(shell);
```

I'm assuming that R.id.shell is in your main XML, because otherwise you couldn't do this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
shell = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shell);
```

If that is correct, there is no reason for the setContentView, as it is allready in the main you've just set.

Comment: and don't forget: call `setContentView()` only once!

Comment: That makes sense the app runs now... Just have to figure out how to run scripts from the shell on my PC as there is no interface in the app itself *cheers

Comment: I have just updated my post with a new error if you have suggestions on how to fix it that would be great *cheers